# Trouble storing files with Archive::Zip: I get empty zip files without error code

Tags: perl, zip, archive

When I try to create zip archives via Archive::Zip there are no errors thrown, but the resulting zip file is broken.

```
use Archive::Zip;

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
my $file = "/a/very/long/path/with/191/characters/file.txt";

if(-f $file)
{
  $zip->addFile("$file", "destinationname.txt");
  print "$file added\n";
}
unless ($zip->writeToFileNamed("out.zip") == "AZ_OK") { die "error";};
```

Now my out.zip file is just 22B and is empty:

```
$> > unzip -l out.zip
Archive:  out.zip
warning [out.zip]:  zipfile is empty
```

What goes wrong?

**First Update**: Everything works fine when I use files with a shorter path name. Any idea for a workaround? Symlinking does not work.

**Second update**: This works as a workaround:

```
use File::Slurp;
[...]
my $text = read_file($file);
$zip->addString($text, "destinationfile.txt");
[..]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to: `$zip->addFile($plmxmlFile);`.

`$zip` is already reference to your target file and by adding name of file you'd use for output, you're making `Archive::Zip` try read and write from same file on assembling attempt, creating a mess (and just generally doing not what your really wanted).

Comment: Does not work. I edited this mistake to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you're not missing root folder leading `/` in file path?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see why your program creates an empty zip file, but you are misusing quotation marks in several places.

In particular the value `AZ_OK` is a symbol for a numeric value that you can import by request.

The `writeToFileNamed` method will never return the string `"AZ_OK"` and also you should compare strings using `eq` instead of `==`.

Fortunately (or not, depending on your point of view) these two errors together with your failure to import the value of `AZ_OK` and your omission of `use warnings` will compare the return value of `writeToFileNamed` with zero (the proper value of `AZ_OK`) and should give you the correct results.

Try this program instead.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES );

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new;
my $file = 'a/very/long/path/with/191/characters/file.txt';

if (-f $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file, 'destinationname.txt');
  print "$file added\n";
}

my $status = $zip->writeToFileNamed('out.zip');
$status == AZ_OK or die "error $status";
```

---

**Update**

The length of the path is unlikely to make any difference unless it is hundreds of characters long.

Try this version and tell us what you get.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES );

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new;
my $file = 'a/very/long/path/with/191/characters/file.txt';

unlink 'out.zip';

die qq(File "$file" not found) unless -f $file;
$zip->addFile($file, 'destinationname.txt');
print "$file added\n";

my $status = $zip->writeToFileNamed('out.zip');
$status == AZ_OK or die "error $status";
```

Comment: @d135-1r43: I have modified the code a little. Please try the amended version in my answer.

Comment: Same behaviour as before. No error message (last line of code) is displayed.

Comment: @d135-1r43: then I am sorry - this is not a place to teach you how to debug. Try some things yourself and we will help if you get stuck

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I will try to get some debug information out of Archive/Zip.pm.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i have understood what is the problem : 
 you use the full root `a/very/long/path/with/191/characters/file.txt`

so you compress all directories in you zip, your file is empty because your are note able to see the path.
  use chdir 
 `chdir 'a/very/long/path/with/191/characters/'`